# SQL WHERE Statement With Multiple Account Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean, where-clause

I'm working with a SQL query and I need to display a set of information, but I have 5 records to display. The following query isn't working:

```
SELECT m.customer_number, m.last_name, m.billing_address_line_1, m.billing_address_line_2, m.billing_city, m.billing_state, m.phone_number1, c.equipment_serial_no, c.make, c.model_number, c.color_code 
FROM customer_master as m
INNER JOIN equip_master as c ON m.customer_number = c.customer_number
WHERE m.customer_number = '19975107' AND '1039283' AND '39203821' AND '23824917' AND '1833729'
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 An expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '19978107'

Comment: Use `IN` operator or `OR` operator.

Answer (score 6):

That's not a valid syntax. If you want to get the list of `customer_number` then use `IN` clause.

```
....
WHERE m.customer_number in('19975107', '1039283', '39203821' 
                           ,'23824917' , '1833729')
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have syntax error in your query.
It must be written like this

```
SELECT m.customer_number, m.last_name, m.billing_address_line_1,m.billing_address_line_2, m.billing_city, m.billing_state, m.phone_number1, c.equipment_serial_no, c.make, c.model_number, c.color_code 

FROM customer_master as m

INNER JOIN equip_master as c

ON m.customer_number = c.customer_number

WHERE m.customer_number = '19975107' OR m.customer_number='1039283' OR m.customer_number='39203821' OR   m.customer_number='23824917' OR m.customer_number ='1833729';
```

Note: Since customer_number is a primary key hence no two customer can have same value of it. Hence using AND is logically incorrect it will return empty set.